# Very basic eruby form issue: Cannot get submit button to do anything

Tags: html, ruby, forms, eruby

This is in my .erb file:

```
<form  method="post" action="/login" id="login" enctype="text/plain"> 
Username: <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here">
Password: <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here">
<%= @error (will display if wrong) %>
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this is in my .rb file:

```
post '/login' do
  #connects to database
  if #connection successful
    # does something
  else
    #do something else
  end
end
```

However, when I try to click my "Submit" button to log in, nothing happens. Originally I was connecting to a database and checking for info, but after that I was just trying to set an error message to be a certain value, and even that won't work. I know this is something silly I'm missing. What piece is not there? (Using Postgres with Eruby, and it's running on Heroku.)

Answer (score 0):

You’re using the [`button` type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage//states-of-the-type-attribute.html#button-state-%28type=button%29) of `input`, for which the docs say:

> The input element represents a button with no default behavior.

This type of `input` control is usually used when you want to attach some javascript behaviour to a button. For submitting a form, you want [`type=submit`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage//states-of-the-type-attribute.html#submit-button-state-%28type=submit%29):

> The input element represents a button that, when activated, submits the form.

So in your Erb file, change this line:

```
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit" />
```